# map/set no deferenceable after using map.erase

Tags: c++, debugging, dictionary, assertion

I am getting a map/set not dereferanceable debug assertion error in my code and I have no idea how to fix it, I have pinpointed the problem to the map.erase in my Shape::insert function however I have no idea how to stop the problem from happening any help is appreciated thanks

If I remove the erase function it works however I need it to erase the items from the map so that they aren't used by those functions anymore

ShapeDraw.h

```
#ifndef _SHAPE_
#define _SHAPE_
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <commdlg.h>
struct CardData
{
    int _x;
    int _y;
    LPCWSTR _filename;
    int _value;
    int _suit = 0; //0 - Hearts, 1 - Diamonds, 2 - Spaces, 3 - Clubs
    bool _face = 0; //0 - Face Down, 1 - Face Up <-- This bit is only used for adding the cards to the stacks and shit
};
struct cardStackList;
class Shape
{

public:
    cardStackList *stack[11];
    //extern cardStackList *stack[11];
    //static HBITMAP mBkg;
    int g_width = 10; //Default Pen Size is 10,
    int g_pen = PS_SOLID;
    int pCountMax = pCount;
    int pCount = 0; //Painting Count
    std::map<int, CardData> _cardMatrix;
    std::map<int, CardData>::iterator _rCardIter;
    cardStackList* make_stack();
    void insert(cardStackList *_stack);
    void CreateStacks();
    cardStackList* remove(cardStackList *_stack); //Remove the top most card
    cardStackList* search(cardStackList *_stack, int _value, int _suit);
    void display(cardStackList *_stack); //Draw Cards in descending order
    Shape()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            stack[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

ShapeDraw.cpp

```
#include "ShapeDraw.h"
struct cardStackList
{
    int _x;
    int _y;
    LPCWSTR _filename;
    int _value;
    int _suit;
    struct cardStackList *next;
    struct cardStackList *prev;
    bool _face; //0 - Face Down, 1 - Face Up
}*stack[11];
cardStackList* Shape::make_stack()
{
    int i;
    struct cardStackList *temp;
    temp = new(struct cardStackList);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        i = rand() % (_cardMatrix.size());
        _rCardIter = _cardMatrix.find(i);
        temp->_x = _rCardIter->second._x;
        temp->_y = _rCardIter->second._y;
        temp->_filename = _rCardIter->second._filename;
        temp->_value = _rCardIter->second._value;
        temp->_suit = _rCardIter->second._suit;
        temp->_face = _rCardIter->second._face;
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev = NULL;
        _cardMatrix.erase(_rCardIter);
        pCount--;
        pCountMax = _cardMatrix.size() + 1;
    }
    return temp;
}
void Shape::insert(cardStackList *_stack)
{
    struct cardStackList *temp, *s, *t;
    temp = make_stack();
    s = _stack;
    t = s;
    if (_stack == NULL)
    {
        _stack = temp;
        _stack->next = NULL;
        _stack->prev = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while (s != NULL)
        {
            t = s;
            s = s->next;
        }
        s = temp;
        s->prev = t;
        s->prev->next = s;
    }
}
cardStackList *Shape::remove(cardStackList *_stack)
{
    struct cardStackList *temp, *t, *return_card;
    temp = _stack;
    t = temp;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        t = temp;
        if (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = t;
        }
    }
    temp = t;
    return_card = temp->next;
    temp->next = temp->next->next;
    temp->next->prev = t;
    return return_card;
}
cardStackList *Shape::search(cardStackList *_stack, int _value, int _suit)
{
    struct cardStackList *temp;
    temp = _stack;
    while (temp->_value != _value && temp->_suit != _suit)
    {
        if (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        return temp;
    }
    return NULL; //Only reaches this if the _value and _suit does not exist in that specific stack
}
void Shape::display(cardStackList *_stack)
{

    struct cardStackList *_slot[11];
    /*
    slots 7 to 10 are the Ace Slots
    */
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        _slot[i] = stack[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        while (_slot[i] != NULL)
        {

        }
    }
}
void Shape::CreateStacks()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        insert(stack[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        insert(stack[1]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        insert(stack[2]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        insert(stack[3]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        insert(stack[4]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        insert(stack[5]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        insert(stack[6]);
    }
    //Stuff that creates the 7 stacks here
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
_rCardIter = _cardMatrix.find(i);
```

`_cardMatrix` is a map, but `i` is an index (count) of elements within the map.  The find will eventually fail to find the card with the ith index and return the `end` iterator.

As an example, I'll assume your matrix starts out with the card numbers 0..51.  The first card removed is the 23rd card, so the matrix has 51 cards 0..22 and 24..51.  The next time in, you again want the 23rd card.  `find` won't find that, since that card has been removed, and the iterator you will get will be `_cardMatrix.end()`, which can not be dereferenced.